# Printing string array stored data on screen in (servlets)

Tags: java

I'm learning about servlets in java. Bellow is my code that is suppose to get the content of the url, store it in array list and, display it on the screen. for some reason I'm unable to get the string array content to displayed on the screen. When I load the page I get the "no luck" message. Any ideas why? thanks

```
//package fortune;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@WebServlet(name = "FortuneServlet", urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class FortuneServlet extends HttpServlet {
    //private String [] cookies = null;
    List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
    String line ;
    public void geturl(String[] args) {

        try 
        {
         URL url = new URL(" http://fortunes.cat-v.org/openbsd/");
             //URL url = new URL(" http://bbc.com");
         // read text returned by server
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

         while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
              cookies.add(line);
              //line = in.readLine();
         }
            in.close();    
    }
        catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void init() throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    protected  void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        if (cookies != null) 
        {
            //response.getWriter().println(
              //  cookies[new Random().nextInt(cookies.length)] 
            //);            
            for (String str: cookies) 
            {
             Collections.shuffle(cookies);  
            response.getWriter().println(str);
            }  
        } 

        else {
            response.getWriter().println("No luck!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, exceptions ? or what output are you getting ?

Comment: no I'm not getting any errors! and I get a blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cookies` is always an empty list (unless you are not showing something to us), so you always shuffle it and try to display, but because you don't have anything there you see a blank page.

I would change check `cookies != null` to `!cookies.isEmpty()`.

EDIT:
You are not adding anything to the `cookies` list, so it is empty (`List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<>();`).
Maybe you wanted to call `geturl` (which does some `add` on the `cookies` list) method somewhere in the doGet? Right now it is not used anywhere.

Comment: Ok if I change it to !cookies.isEmpty() it displays the "no luck!" message

Comment: nope, I still need to get the result to display on the screen. so it appears I'm not filling the array list properly

Comment: @zamzam but the problem with blank page is solved? If so please mark the answer as such. If not please rephrase your question (by editing it).

Comment: thanks for the edit to your answer I'm still confused about the issue, could you elaborate a bit more on the solution? thanks

Comment: never mind your initial guide was enough! thank you for your time